# My app is crashing due to UITextField text entering procedure

Tags: objective-c

User can tap the next UITextField to enter data or can touch next button on Keyboard.
I have used textFieldShouldReturn method to add text object to array. It works well until I touch next UITextfield to enter data instead of touching next on keyboard and then since no data is added to my array, later in segue, UITableViewController crashes.

Do I need to implement both method or am something wrong here.

**ModalViewController.m**

```
@interface ModalViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *arrayToReturn;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *bookTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pageTextField;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet customAddBookButton *doneButton;


@end

@implementation ModalViewController



#pragma mark- textField Delegate

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn");
    if (textField == self.bookTextField) {

        [self.pageTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if (textField == self.pageTextField){
                if ([self.bookTextField.text isEqual:@""]) {
            [self.bookTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        }else {
            [self.pageTextField resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }

    [arrayToReturn insertObject:self.bookTextField.text atIndex:0];
    [arrayToReturn insertObject:self.pageTextField.text atIndex:1];


    return YES;
}


#pragma mark- Done button action
- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender {

    self.bookMetaReturnedfromModalView (arrayToReturn);
    NSLog(@"array is %@", arrayToReturn);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}






#pragma mark- viewDidLoad

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.bookTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    arrayToReturn = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


}





@end
```

**crash log**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011089df65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110315deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110781a94 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 212
    3   BookApp                             0x000000010fe0722d -[AddBooksTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 413
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000110fc06b3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 782
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000110fc07c8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000110f96650 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3187
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000110fc9595 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000110fb19ad -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 218
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000110f2211c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
    10  QuartzCore                          0x000000011547736a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000011546bbd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000011546ba4e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    13  QuartzCore                          0x00000001154601d5 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000011548d9f0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000011548e154 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107c99d7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107c9947 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107bf59b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107bee98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000114f2aad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000110e71676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    22  BookApp                             0x000000010fe082cf main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011316792d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Can you add the crash log?

Comment: Since I am just using textFieldShouldReturn method and if I don't return via keyboard press (next or enter key) and simply tap next UITextField to enter data there is nothing being added to array since textField is returning null. Do I need to implement same adding of data in textFieldShouldEndEditing method too.

Comment: show the code. we cant really help unles u post the crash log and the code related to it

Comment: I have added code of my ModalViewController

Comment: Update your question by pointing out which line is causing the crash.

Comment: Hello, rmaddy, the problem is that array is filled only when keyboard enter key is pressed to go to next textField and so on. If instead I just tap next textfield to enter data and ten touch done button array remain empty.

Comment: move you array filling code to `textFieldDidEndEditing:` or `textFieldShouldEndEditing` and it should works

Answer (score 0):

After adding objects to array in textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange method array is being populated simultaneously and everything is working fine.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


    if (textField == self.bookTextField) {
        [arrayToReturn insertObject:[[self.bookTextField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] atIndex:0];
    }else if (textField == self.pageTextField){
        [arrayToReturn insertObject:[[self.pageTextField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] atIndex:1];
    }


     return YES;
}
```